# Index Rebuild Takes Time Causing Timeouts

Tags: sql-server, indexing, rebuild

We are using SQL Server Standard Edition (AWS RDS).

We are using index rebuild tool by [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html).

This rebuild agent job takes time causing timeouts.

We divided this job into two, first containing rebuild for one single large table and the other containing rebuild for other database tables. These are scheduled at different times.

The first job (for rebuilding a single large table) is the one causing the issue.

Can someone please suggest some ways to fix the issue?

Comment: How often do you do the rebuild? Why are the indexes of the table fragmented ? What are the wait types you see when the index is rebuilding?

Comment: Please precise, is it a job that rebuilds the index times out or it causes table to be offline and you call it "timeout"?

Comment: If you saying about your table that is offline for a long time and since you are on Standard you cannot use online rebuild, your option is REORGANIZE

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts Our rebuild job runs daily. It also updates statistics. This rebuild job takes around 15 minutes occasionally. The table is highly transactional i.e., it observes many inserts and updates on daily basis. May be that is causing fragmentation.

Comment: @sepupic When this rebuild job is running and we try to query table during that time, we get timeout error.

Comment: @sepupic Yes, REBUILD ONLINE is available in Enterprise Edition. We use REORGANIZE for medium level fragmentation and REBUILD OFFLINE for high level fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ONLINE` rebuild is not an oprion for you (Enterprise only and you are on Standard), `ALTER INDEX..REORGANIZE` is your option.

> Reorganizing an index uses minimal system resources. It defragments
>   the leaf level of clustered and nonclustered indexes on tables and
>   views by physically reordering the leaf-level pages to match the
>   logical, left to right, order of the leaf nodes. Reorganizing also
>   compacts the index pages. Compaction is based on the existing fill
>   factor value.

This is not offline operation, It blocks only a page it's working on, it's not performed as one transaction (offline rebuild is done in 1 transaction) and you can interrupt it when you want. The work done will not be lost, the next time you exec REORGANIZE it will start with the point where it was stopped previously:

> Reorganize: This option is more lightweight. It runs through the leaf
>   level of the index, and as it goes it fixes physical ordering of pages
>   and also compacts pages to apply any previously set fillfactor
>   settings. This operation is always online, and if you cancel it then
>   it’s able to just stop where it is (it doesn’t have a giant operation
>   to rollback).

[Rebuild or Reorganize: SQL Server Index Maintenance](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/index-maintenance-sql-server-rebuild-reorganize/)